# What does the localic reflection of a classifying topos classify?

Tags: topos-theory, locales, categorical-logic

Let $\mathbb{T}$ be a geometric theory. Let $\mathrm{Set}[\mathbb{T}]$ be its classifying topos, such that geometric morphisms from any (cocomplete) topos $\mathcal{E}$ into $\mathrm{Set}[\mathbb{T}]$ are in canonical one-to-one correspondence with models of $\mathbb{T}$ in $\mathcal{E}$.

As with any topos, associated to $\mathrm{Set}[\mathbb{T}]$ is its *localic reflection* $L(\mathrm{Set}[\mathbb{T}])$, the locale which has the partially ordered set $\mathrm{Sub}_{\mathrm{Set}[\mathbb{T}]}(1)$ as frame of opens. Like any locale, this locale is the classifying locale of some propositional geometric theory $\mathbb{T}'$.

**Question:** Can the theory $\mathbb{T}'$ be described in terms of $\mathbb{T}$?

For instance, let $\mathbb{T}$ the theory of an object, containing a single sort and no axioms. Then $\mathrm{Set}[\mathbb{T}]$ is the *object classifier*, the copresheaf topos $[\mathrm{FinSet}, \mathrm{Set}]$. Its localic reflection is the one-point locale, so $\mathbb{T}'$ is the empty theory.

My motivation is that I want to find out whether a certain geometric $\mathcal{F} \to \mathcal{E}$ morphism is open. For this, I have to check whether its localic reflection is open (as a locale internal to $\mathcal{E}$); if I knew which theory the localic reflection classifies, I'd have a handle on this.

An obvious place to look for an answer would be Olivia Caramello's [beautiful paper on lattices of theories](https://arxiv.org/abs/0905.0299). However, there she discusses only subtoposes, not the localic reflection.

Comment: We computed the localic reflection using geometric methods in Thm 24 here: https://arxiv.org/abs/1310.0705 The methods are more general, and you will find more information in the work by Steve Vickers. Unfortunately, I don't have time to find the precise references now.

Comment: In general, I think one can only say the obvious thing: T' is the " theory of geometric formula without free variables of T ". (i.e. a propositional theory which has one proposition for each geometric proposition of T without free variables and which proves exactly the same implication between these propositions as T does.)

Comment: I think the object classifier example isn't correct. The localic reflection of the object classifier is the Sierpinski space (classifying the theory with one proposition symbol); the nontrivial geometric formula without free variables in the one sort theory is "the sort is inhabited".