# Does the functor $\mathrm{Sh}\colon\mathbf{Top}\to\mathbf{Topos}$ have an adjoint?

Tags: ct.category-theory, gn.general-topology, topos-theory, locales

Consider the category $\mathbf{Top}$ of topological spaces, the category $\mathbf{Topos}$ of toposes and geometric morphisms, and the category $\mathbf{Loc}$ of locales. Let
$$\mathrm{Sh}\colon\mathbf{Top}\to\mathbf{Topos}$$
be the functor sending a space $X$ to the topos of sheaves on $X$. Does this functor have a left or a right adjoint?

Of course, $\mathrm{Sh}$ factorizes as
$$\mathbf{Top}\to\mathbf{Loc}\to\mathbf{Topos},$$
since the sheaves on $X$ are the sheaves on the locale of open subsets of $X$.

It is well-known that $\mathbf{Top}\to\mathbf{Loc}$ has a right adjoint and $\mathbf{Loc}\to\mathbf{Topos}$ has a left adjoint ($\mathbf{Loc}$ is reflective in $\mathbf{Topos}$). So the question whether $\mathrm{Sh}$ has a left adjoint reduces to the question whether $\mathbf{Top}\to\mathbf{Loc}$ has a left adjoint and the question whether $\mathrm{Sh}$ has a right adjoint reduces to the question whether $\mathbf{Loc}\to\mathbf{Topos}$ has a right adjoint.

*Remark.* I already asked this on math.SE but I didn't get an answer.

Comment: Are your toposes Grothendieck toposes?

Comment: Are the reductions you give meant to be "if and only if" reductions? Clearly if $Loc \to Topos$ and $Top \to Loc$ had these additional adjoints then so would $Top \to Topos$, but the converse is not clear (to me) (though see my comment on Dmitri Pavlov's answer below).

Comment: "I already asked this on math.SE but I didn't get an answer" Well, I left a comment there with which you could have find an answer yourself. (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4217568/) Notice that Dmitri's answer exactly follows that suggestion.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In this answer, Topos is interpreted as a 2-category.
(As a side remark, the 1-category of toposes does not make sense
until one picks a specific model for toposes and geometric morphisms, and different models
need not be equivalent as 1-categories.
For the 1-categorical framework to make sense, at the very least
one needs to organize toposes into a relative category,
so that different models can be shown to be Dwyer–Kan equivalent as relative categories.)

> whether Top→Loc has a left adjoint

The functor Top→Loc does not have a left adjoint because it does not preserve finite products.
For example, the product of rational numbers with themselves
as locales and as topological spaces produces nonisomorphic locales.
In particular, rational numbers form a topological group, but not a localic group.

> whether Loc→Topos has a right adjoint

Loc→Topos does not have a right adjoint because it does not preserve homotopy colimits.

For example, suppose G is a discrete group acting on a point.
Then the colimit of this action in locales is again a point.
But the homotopy colimit of this action in toposes
is the delooping of G, which is not equivalent to a point.

Thus, both Loc→Topos and Top→Topos do not have a right adjoint functor.

Comment: Because $Loc \to Topos$ is fully faithful, it reflects limits (as well as colimits). So your first point -- that $Top \to Loc$ does not preserve finite products -- implies that $Top \to Topos$ also does not preserve finite products. So $Top \to Topos$ does not have a left adjoint. Your second point starts to make it matter exactly what is meant by "category" here -- you seem to be treating $Topos$ as at least a $(2,1)$-category.

Comment: @Dmitri: Thanks. But this doesn't answer whether Top -> Topos has a right adjoint.

Comment: Isn’t the location reflection, described here https://mathoverflow.net/questions/271096/what-does-the-localic-reflection-of-a-classifying-topos-classify a right adjoint?  I’m not an expert

Comment: If I recall you take subobjects of the terminal object as a frame.  This may require the topos to be Grothendieck but this is stuff I learned by osmosis so might be off.

Comment: @TimCampion: Everything is treated bicategorically here, since Topos is a bicategory.  The 1-category of toposes is not a well-defined notion until you pick a specific model (and different models need not be equivalent as 1-categories).

Comment: @user333306: It does answer your question, since the example in the last paragraph is a counterexample to the claim that Top→Topos has a right adjoint.  A left adjoint must necessarily preserve the indicated homotopy colimit, which is not the case with Top→Topos.

Comment: @DmitriPavlov Ah, thanks. But what about the localic reflection Benjamin Steinberg mentioned. Isn't it a right adjoint of Loc -> Topos?

Comment: @user333306: The localic reflection is the _left_ adjoint of the inclusion Loc→Topos.  See, for example, the nLab: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/locale#RelationToToposes

Comment: Ah, of course! :-)

Comment: I think to stay as close as possible to the spirit of the question makes the most sense to view the involved categories as (2,1)-categories. Otherwise there arises the question whether Loc should be viewed as locally ordered or locally discrete. One is most natural when comparing with spaces, the other when comparing with toposes.

Comment: @JonasFrey: For the locally ordered version of Loc, which comparison result do you have in mind?

Comment: I think if we say that Loc is reflective in the (2,2)-category Topos, then we're speaking about the locally ordered category of locales?

Comment: @JonasFrey: I see, you were talking about reflection for noninvertible 2-morphisms of toposes.  Originally, I had in mind the minimal required modification of OP's statement, which only adds invertible 2-morphisms, but the arguments continue to make sense for noninvertible 2-morphisms.

Comment: @DmitriPavlov: I agree with you that admitting only invertible 2-cells is "the minimal required modification" and the best way of looking at the question. But the point I was trying to make is in the setting with non-invertible 2-cells the decomposition Top --> Loc --> Topos has to be replaced by Top --> Loc_0 --> Loc --> Topos, where Loc_0 has disctrete homs, and Loc has ordered ones. Then the first functor has a right adjoint and the last one has a left adjoint,  and I don't know about the middle one.